# How to invoke programmatically "http post" on Sharepoint

Tags: user, domain, trusted-domain

I'm encountering some problem adding by code users from another domain (in my farm I have trust for 2 domain).
If I use People Picker, everything goes fine... So I ask u.. It's possible to create an http request like the one called by poeple picker? Something like:

```
HTTP 1.1    
POST /sites/MySite/_layouts/aclinv.aspx?GroupId=147&IsDlg=1 HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
```

How can i do to repropose this scenario? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the stand WebRequest class in asp.net

```
HttpWebRequest userReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
userReq.AllowAutoRedirect=false;
userReq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "PASS", "<url>");
HttpWebResponse serverResponse = (HttpWebResponse) userReq.GetResponse();
```

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius